# phpmyadmin Error : PHP 7.1.3+ is required. Currently installed version is: 7.0.27

Tags: xampp

Using Moc OS

I was using XAMPP  7.0.27 and 
Now updated to XAMPP 7.2.28

After Upgrading not able to open PhpMyAdmin Page using
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Getting Following Error on Page

> PHP 7.1.3+ is required.
>   Currently installed version is: 7.0.27

What Should be done to open phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: Update your php version should do the trick? Maybe this helps https://medium.com/@smile2gether/how-to-update-php-version-on-mac-os-x-5d4b91b2c1f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems something didn't get upgraded properly or there's a conflict, because XAMPP 7.2.28 should come with PHP version 7.2.28.

Have you some other PHP installation, perhaps you at one time tried to install your own PHP outside of XAMPP? I suggest removing any other installations to as to avoid conflicts. Your MacOS probably comes with PHP, which could be the conflict.

You could start with the XAMPP control panel to verify which is installed, which PHP is being used by XAMPP, and checking that everything is working together. The installer should have put all the pieces in the right places, so if after all that it still isn't working, I suggest reinstalling XAMPP.